# Basic HTML editor in Mac

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am new to Cocoa. I need to build a basic HTML editor in Cocoa. The user will basically will be formatting text etc but he/she does not know that the text will be saved as HTML. Should I be using NSText View or should I be using WebView.  Also if there any tutorials are available for building basic HTML editor.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12492150/143378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an `NSTextView`. You can save the text as an `NSAttributedString` and read from the html file into an `NSAttributedString`. [Here's](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/135136-displaying-html-in-an-nstextview.html) some info on that to get you started.