# HTML editor Cocoa control

Tags: html, cocoa, editor, controls

I am looking for a Cocoa HTML editor control.
Do you know if something like this already exists?

Answer (score 4):

Here's [CKEditor4ObjC](https://github.com/robotmedia/CKEditor4ObjC), an open-source Cocoa HTML editor using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and `WebView` that I just created.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Apologies. I'll add Apache 2.0 when I have a minute.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that I've seen that relates to what you're looking for is [this simple example](http://www.paullynch.org/blog/?p=257) of how to use the TinyMCE JavaScript-based HTML editor in a Cocoa `WebView`.

Alternatively, I would take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832950/basic-html-editor-in-mac) and the corresponding link to helpful information that resides within it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to use `document.execCommand(...)` either, because WebKit is pretty compatible with it.